# $ is not a function errors

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

I'm getting a few Javascript errors and was wondering if anyone could help me out with them. I'm fairly new to js and could really use the help. That being said here is the page with the errors. http://www.gotopeak.com .

Here is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
>   error is on line 44

Here is the code:

```
    var hoverButton = {
    init : function() {     
        arrButtons = $$('.hover_button');

        for (var i=0; i<arrButtons.length; i++) {
            arrButtons[i].addEvent('mouseover', hoverButton.setOver);   
            arrButtons[i].addEvent('mouseout', hoverButton.setOff);
        }

    },
    setOver : function() {
        buttonImageSource = this.src;
        this.src = buttonImageSource.replace('_off.', '_hover.');
    }, 
    setOff : function() {
        buttonImageSource = this.src;
        if (buttonImageSource.indexOf('_hover.') != -1) {
            this.src = buttonImageSource.replace('_hover.', '_off.');
        }
    }
}

window.addEvent('domready', hoverButton.init);



var screenshots = {
    numScreens : 0,
    currScreen : 0,
    screenContainerAnimation : null,
    screenFadeSpeed : 200,
    animating : false,
    initialized: false,     

    init : function() {
        var arrScreens = $$('#screen_container .screenshot');
        screenshots.numScreens = arrScreens.length;

        screenshots.screenContainerAnimation = new Fx.Tween('screen_container', {
            duration: 300,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut
        });

        var indicatorMold = $('indicatorMold');

        for(i=0; i<arrScreens.length; i++) { 

            var screenShot = arrScreens[i];
            screenShot.id = 'screenshot' + (i+1);

            var screenIndicator = indicatorMold.clone();
            screenIndicator.id = 'indicator' + (i+1);
            screenIndicator.inject('screen_indicators');
            screenIndicator.href = 'javascript: screenshots.setActiveScreen('+ (i+1)*1 +')';            

            screenShot.removeClass('hidden');               

            if (i==0) {
                var initialScreenHeight = screenShot.getCoordinates().height;
                $('screen_container').setStyle('height', initialScreenHeight);
                screenshots.currScreen = 1;
                screenIndicator.addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                screenShot.setStyle('opacity',0);
                screenShot.setStyle('display','none');
            }           

        } // loop

        screenshots.initialized = true;
    },

    next : function() {
        if (screenshots.initialized) {
            var nextNum = screenshots.currScreen + 1;

            if (nextNum > screenshots.numScreens) {
                nextNum = 1;
            }

            screenshots.setActiveScreen(nextNum);
        }

        return false;
    },

    previous : function() {
        if (screenshots.initialized) {
            var prevNum = screenshots.currScreen - 1;

            if (prevNum < 1) {
                prevNum = screenshots.numScreens;
            }

            screenshots.setActiveScreen(prevNum);
        }

        return false;
    },

    setActiveScreen : function(screenNum) {
        if(screenshots.animating == false) {
            screenshots.animating = true;
            var currScreen = $('screenshot' + screenshots.currScreen);
            var currIndicator = $('indicator' + screenshots.currScreen);
            var newScreen = $('screenshot' + screenNum);
            var newIndicator = $('indicator' + screenNum);

            currScreen.set('tween', {
                duration: screenshots.screenFadeSpeed,
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut,
                onComplete: function() { 
                    currIndicator.removeClass('active');
                    currScreen.setStyle('display','none') ;
                }
            }); 
            currScreen.tween('opacity', 0); 

            function resizeScreen() {       
                newScreen.setStyle('display','block');
                var newScreenSize = newScreen.getCoordinates().height;
                screenshots.screenContainerAnimation.start('height', newScreenSize);
            }

            function fadeInNewScreen() {

                newScreen.set('tween', {
                    duration: screenshots.screenFadeSpeed,
                    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut,
                    onComplete: function() { 
                        newIndicator.addClass('active'); 
                        screenshots.animating = false;  
                    }
                });
                newScreen.tween('opacity', 1);
            }

            resizeScreen.delay(screenshots.screenFadeSpeed);
            fadeInNewScreen.delay(screenshots.screenFadeSpeed + 400);

            screenshots.currScreen = screenNum;
        }
    }
}

window.addEvent('load', screenshots.init)   ;
```

I would be very grateful and appreciative of any help that I receive on this issue.

Comment: Can someone explain why various places OP is using "$$"?  For example: "arrButtons = $$('.hover_button');"

Comment: This looks like MooTools to me. There's not a single bit of jQuery in that code.

Comment: I believe it is mootools. I inherited this project so I was not 100% sure what original dev used.

Comment: @Chris in Mootools the $ is used to get an element by id like the native document.getElementById('id-string');  whereas the $$ is used for shorthand to the native document.querySelector('.class li'); jQuery doesn't provide an api for getElementById (although their $ function looks for a string that starts with # and defaults to the native getElementById).

Answer (score 5):

Your page is loading mootools once, jQuery twice and jQuery UI twice. Because both jQuery and mootools define a function named '$', this gives you conflicts.

You can fix this by using a self executing closure that maps the non-conflicted version of '$' to a local '$' variable you can actually use.

```
(function($) {
    // your code
})(document.id);
```

More information on MooTools' "Dollar Safe Mode" can be found [here](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: please ignore. The above answer by igorw is the correct one. Sorry.

Try converting your $ symbols to "jQuery". $ is a shortcut to JQuery. $ is reserved for Prototype in Wordpress.

Edit: you can also try jQuery.noConflict(). It relinquishes control of $ back to JQuery (or the first library that implements it), so it does not cause conflict with other libraries that also implement $.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive, so it should be jQuery, not JQuery.

Comment: The code is actually MooTools, and I've edited the tags to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Forgot to add mootools to the tags.

Comment: This thread has some more ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812359/mootools-and-jquery-conflict-despite-dollar-safe-mode

Comment: since when is $ reserved for prototype in wordpress?

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. Checking out that solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did and solved everything, Go to the index.php file, after calling jquery immediately, place `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>`